# Left Join with OR taking forever to run

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, left-join

I've spent a long writing a join that finally gets all the criteria I need, but it's taking forever to run. Any ideas on how to speed this up? I've attached a link to the query plan below, however I'm not 100% sure how to read it and find the choke point of the query.

```
SELECT
  A.procedure_code
  ,a.modifier_one
 ,A.invoice_id
 ,A.invoice_service_date
 ,A.procedure_total_billed_fee
 ,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, A.invoice_service_date), 0) AS VisitMonth
 ,A.facility_name
 ,A.invoice_insert_date
 ,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, A.invoice_insert_date), 0) AS InvoiceInsertMonth
 ,A.claim_entry_date
 ,A.claim_last_modify_date
 ,A.primary_insurance_name
 ,A.primary_payer_level_three
 ,A.patient_id
 ,A.procedure_id
 ,D.[MedicareRate]
 ,a.cms_locality_name
FROM
 CIPBackUps.cip.[2020_02_05_month_end_services] A
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT [MedicareRate],[Locality Name],[Locality Number],HCPCS, [mod] FROM TESTDB.dbo.[medicare2018] WHERE [Medicare Administrative Contractor (MAC)] = '4412')  D 
  ON a.cms_locality_number = D.[Locality number] AND 
   (
    (concat(A.procedure_code,a.modifier_one) = concat(D.HCPCS,d.mod) AND a.modifier_one in ('','TC','26','53') AND procedure_code NOT IN ('99281','99282','99283','99284','99285','99291','99292') ) 
    OR (A.procedure_code = D.HCPCS AND a.modifier_one NOT in ('','TC','26','53')
    OR (A.procedure_code = D.HCPCS AND (a.modifier_one IS NULL or procedure_code IN ('99281','99282','99283','99284','99285','99291','99292')) )) AND A.procedure_code NOT LIKE 'G%'
   )
WHERE 
 procedure_total_billed_fee <> 0
 AND a.invoice_service_date between '10/01/2018' AND '12/31/2018 23:59:59'
```

[Paste the Plan Link](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1sVLaHV8)

Comment: You haven't shown the plan.

Comment: @Blindy updated with the plan now.

Comment: Does the table `2020_02_05_month_end_services` have an index on the `modifier_one` column?  The plan looks like it is doing a table scan on that table, and you do multiple `IN` and `NOT IN` operations on that column...  The same goes for the `procedure_code` column.

Comment: @JamesL. Yes, I double checked the indexes on those columns still to no avail. I know the two ORs in the join cause it take take forever and if I execute each portion of it alone it goes quickly, but I can't figure out how to do the query without the ORs

Comment: When `OR`s cause a problem, sometimes the solution is a `UNION ALL` with the 2 separate conditions. At whatever level of your query you can manage it.

Comment: How long does the query run currently? Put a `-- ` in front both `OR` statements to comment it. What's the runtime in seconds? Then, remove `-- ` to uncomment the first `OR`. What's the runtime in seconds? Then, comment the first `OR` and uncomment the second `OR`. What's the runtime? Then, comment the `(concat(A.procedure_code,a.modifier_one)` line and remove the `OR` from the next line. What's the runtime?

Comment: You want `CONCAT` because there can be a situation like `concat('123', '45') = concat('12', '345')`? Or would `a.procedure_code = d.hcpcs AND ,a.modifier_one = d.mod` suffice?

Comment: Which is the bigger table?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical.)

Comment: @philipxy links are OK for Paste-The-Plan - pretty hard to display that in any meaningful way within the question.

Comment: Please clarify your INTENT of the join.  I don't want you to think implied and/or but to handle explicitly by parenthesis. For brevity.. Locality AND   Please confirm instead of ( A or B AND C)  is your intent  ((A or B) AND C) vs (A or (B and C))?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you don't need `CONCAT`. That would handle the case `CONCAT('123', '45') = CONCAT('12', '345')`, but shouldn't `a.procedure_code = d.hcpcs AND a.modifier_one = d.mod` suffice in a properly built database? If this assumption is true, then you can move the condition `a.procedure_code = d.hcpcs` outside the ORs and the lower part of the query would read:

```
FROM cipbackups.cip.[2020_02_05_month_end_services] a
LEFT JOIN testdb.dbo.[medicare2018] d
    ON d.[Medicare Administrative Contractor (MAC)] = '4412'
   AND a.cms_locality_number = d.[Locality number] 
   AND a.procedure_code = d.hcpcs
   AND
   (
     (
       a.modifier_one = d.mod AND 
       a.modifier_one IN ('','TC','26','53') AND
       a.procedure_code NOT IN ('99281','99282','99283','99284','99285','99291','99292') 
     ) 
     OR
     (
       a.procedure_code NOT LIKE 'G%' 
       AND
       (
         a.modifier_one NOT IN ('','TC','26','53') OR 
         a.modifier_one IS NULL OR
         a.procedure_code IN ('99281','99282','99283','99284','99285','99291','99292') 
       )
     )
   )
WHERE a.procedure_total_billed_fee <> 0
AND a.invoice_service_date >= '2018-10-01' AND a.invoice_service_date < '2019-01-01';
```

In order to find the A rows via `invoice_service_date` and `procedure_total_billed_fee` quickly, you'd probably want this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON cipbackups.cip.[2020_02_05_month_end_services] 
(
  invoice_service_date,
  procedure_total_billed_fee,
  cms_locality_number,
  procedure_code,
  modifier_one
);
```

(If only few rows match `procedure_total_billed_fee <> 0`, then this column may be more selective than `invoice_service_date` and you may want to swap the two columns in the index.)

This gives you `cms_locality_number`, `procedure_code` and `modifier_one` right away, which you want to use to look up D rows. For this to happen quickly you want an index on the related columns:

```
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON testdb.dbo.[medicare2018]
(
  [Medicare Administrative Contractor (MAC)],
  [Locality number],
  hcpcs,
  mod
);
```

(If `[Locality number]` is more selective than `[Medicare Administrative Contractor (MAC)]` you may want to swap their positions. If you are insecure regarding this add another index with the swapped columns and see which is used by the DBMS.)

**UPDATE: One additional idea**

```
       AND
       (
         a.modifier_one NOT IN ('','TC','26','53') OR 
         a.modifier_one IS NULL OR
         a.procedure_code IN ('99281','99282','99283','99284','99285','99291','99292') 
       )
```

is the same as

```
       AND NOT
       (
         a.modifier_one IN ('','TC','26','53') AND
         a.procedure_code NOT IN ('99281','99282','99283','99284','99285','99291','99292') 
       )
```

You can try to replace the former by the latter so as to make it obvious to the DBMS' optimizer that one condition is on

```
       AND
       (
         a.modifier_one IN ('','TC','26','53') AND
         a.procedure_code NOT IN ('99281','99282','99283','99284','99285','99291','99292') 
       )
```

and the other on

```
       AND NOT
       (
         a.modifier_one IN ('','TC','26','53') AND
         a.procedure_code NOT IN ('99281','99282','99283','99284','99285','99291','99292') 
       )
```

I don't know whether this can make a difference, though.